# Where does appwidgetprovider class go?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

Where does `appwidgetprovider` class go? Is it a new `XML` in res-xml, or in `manifest`, appwidgetprovider XML etc. I am using eclipse and am making a widget for an app.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

You must declare your AppWidgetProvider class implementation as a broadcast receiver using the  element in the AndroidManifest.

You should not create a new broadcast receiver as the the AppWidgetProvider class extends BroadcastReceiver. The Widget has the same runtime restrictions as a normal broadcast receiver, i.e., it has only 5 seconds to finish its processing.
Hence the widget should therefore perform time consuming operations in a service and perform the update of the widgets from the service.

It receives following callbacks:

```
onReceive(Context, Intent) //As it extends the BroadCastReceiver.
onUpdate()
onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()
onDeleted(Context, int[])
onEnabled(Context)
onDisabled(Context)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a normal receiver declaring my appwidgetprovider, so I need to make a new broadcast receiver for the class? And i just put the class in the middle of the receiver? I've read the tutorial, but i don't find it so clear